# Cloud IoT Core and Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gateway, google-cloud-iot

I am confused about the difference between gateway and Cloud IoT Core. Here are the [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-gateways-rpi) and the illustration.

[image]

It looks like a gateway is optional. If so, what is the purpose of adding a gateway? What are the different roles played by the gateway and Cloud IoT core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of requirement or use case and the devices that you have with you.

In general, Gateway in IoT environment refers to a class of device that processes data on behalf of a group or cluster of devices.

*Gateways are a powerful feature of Cloud IoT Core that bridges communication between **constrained devices** and Cloud IoT Core.*

That is, the Gateway is a device that connects less capable devices to Cloud IoT Core and performs several tasks on the device's behalf, such as communication, authentication, storage, and processing. It also enables connectivity to the internet when the device cannot directly connect itself, such as a ZigBee or Bluetooth device. It can still leverage the capabilities of Cloud IoT Core and the rest of Google Cloud for processing, analyzing, and visualizing data in real time.

Gateway manages the less capable devices in the IoT environment. The devices shall be directly connected to Cloud IoT Core, but will receive updates from and publish telemetry events to the cloud through the gateway.

The cloud IoT Core is for managing gateways and also the devices that are fully capable on their own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With that being said, is Cloud IoT Core a must? Can devices connect to, say cloud storage, through gateways?

Comment: Gateways operate on behalf of constrained device or group of devices. IoT Core is serverless platform that enables to connect to Google Cloud and has its own other features like scalability for many devices, auto-load balancing, managed service (device identity management, health monitoring), protocol bridge that supports for MQTT/HTTP for connectivity and takes the data to pub/sub. Once the data is in Pub/Sub, it's in Google Cloud. Push subscriptions deliver event to serverless apps in Cloud Functions/App Engine/Cloud Run and pull subscriptions to services in Kubernetes Engine/Cloud Dataflow.